# FreeBSD interface up/down monitoring

Tags: networking, freebsd, network-monitoring, interface, ifconfig

How to get informed about specific interface status in FreeBSD?

```
ifconfig <ifname> | grep "status: active"
```

works fine but I want to avoid polling and be informed as fast as possible about ifup/ifdown.

Comment: Have you researched SNMP traps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`devd(8)` will do the trick. You need to configure it to run an action if `LINK_UP` or `LINK_DOWN` event happened on an interface. A sample configuration to be added to `/etc/devd.conf` or even better, create `/etc/devd/interface.conf`:

```
notify 0 {
    match "system"        "IFNET";
    match "subsystem"     "(em0|em1)";
    match "type"          "LINK_DOWN";
    action "/usr/local/sbin/notifier.sh $subsystem"
}
```

Above configuration assumes that you want to be notified when interface `em0` or `em1` goes down, and invokes the script upon occurrence of the event. It will also pass the interface name (hence `$subsystem`) to the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor up/down event via devd(8). Look at devd.conf(5) for LINK_UP and LINK_DOWN events.